# set_error_handler changed bevahvior leads to error

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have been using the same code snippet for years. It has been working nicely on 3 different websites. I recently started with a new Hoster and, to my surprise, the following error gets logged from 2 to 10 times before the line refering to the programming error itself. For example, if a variable is undefined I get :

```
PHP Warning:  set_error_handler() expects the argument (log_all_errors) to be a valid callback in /home/mysite/public_html/error_handler.php on line 52
```

and afterthat comes the error concerning the variable.

Here a simplified code excerpt :

```
# error_handler.php :

     //defining a custom error_log etc ...
     ini_set('display_errors', NULL);
     define('SEND_ERROR_EMAIL_TO', 'mymail@mail.com');
     set_error_handler('log_all_errors');   

# catching the error :

     include ('error_handler.php');
     function log_all_errors($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) { 
     global $error_type;
     $error_name = (isset($error_type[$errno]) ? $error_type[$errno] : 'Unknown error code - '."'".$_SESSION['ip']."'");
     // defining lock file
     // defining e-mail etc...
     $error_message = $error_name.': '.$errstr.' in '.$errfile.' on line '.$errline;
     error_log($error_message, 0); 
     }
     set_error_handler('log_all_errors');
```

The former server was Apache, now it's ngnix. I've been reading the PHP Manual for hours but I cannot figure out why the argument **log_all_errors**  suddenly stopped being a valid callback.

Comment: You need to define `function  log_all_errors()` *before* doing `set_error_handler('log_all_errors');`.

Comment: Before? Never heard that before. Does it fix the error? What version of PHP is this?

Comment: It was just a thought.

Comment: Is `log_all_errors` inside a class?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat  No, it is not